# set background colour for table when the page loads

Tags: jquery, css

I am a newbie to Jquery so apoligise if this is a silly question

I have seen many ways how to change the background of a table colour but when a certain row is clicked or hovered, however i want to set the background colour of my table to **white** when the page is loaded.

i.e code i have saw is like below

```
 $(function() {
        $('tr').hover(function() {
            $(this).css('background-color', '#FFFF99');
            $(this).contents('td').css({'border': '1px solid red', 'border-left': 'none', 'border-right': 'none'});
            $(this).contents('td:first').css('border-left', '1px solid red');
            $(this).contents('td:last').css('border-right', '1px solid red');
        },
        function() {
            $(this).css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
            $(this).contents('td').css('border', 'none');
        });
    });
```

Comment: What is the issue? A jsfiddle code showing your issue can help you get the answers fast..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write it down this code and it work when page load.....

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $("#table_id").css("background-color", "#FFFF99");
 });
```

where table_id is id of table.....

Comment: Ah ok that works and how do you do it for the row for odd and even is it the same?

Answer (score 3):

You really don't need jquery to be able to do this. This can all be done in plain CSS.

```
tr:hover
{
   background-color:#FFFF99;
}
tr:hover td
{
   styles here...
}
tr:hover td:first
{
   styles here...
}

etc...
```

As for setting the `background-color` on your table, this can be done in plain CSS too:

```
table.myTableClass
{
   background-color:#fff;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To set the background colour of a table try this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#myTable").css("background-color", "#FFF");

    // $("tr").hover(......

});
```

Where `myTable` is the id of your table. However, if this is to always to be done on load of the page, put it in CSS as that's what it's designed for.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code,

```
        $('table').css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
        $('table').contents('td').css('border', 'none');
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TdyZm/3/) sample